# how to determine current MaxClients in Ubuntu 14.04 running Apache2

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2 and have placed the following line in my `apache2.conf` file:

```
MaxClients 1024
```

I have also restarted Apache.

Is there any way I can verify that the `MaxClients 1024` line was properly read and parsed? In other words, is there a way I can determine the server's current MaxClients value from a source other than the config file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may verify `MaxClients` by loading the
[mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html) module.

To configure mod_info, add the following to your `httpd.conf` file :

```
<Location "/server-info">
    SetHandler server-info
</Location>
```

That information, and much more, is then accessed via the page
http://localhost/server-info.